# How to simplify nested conditional for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have this for loop for creating a list of variables:

```
vars <- c( 'beta.o', 'sd.y') 
for (x in c('ghs', 'site', 'trt')) {
  if(model.parms[[x]] == 1) {
    data <- data[, which(names(data) != x)]
  } else {
    data <- data
    if(x!='ghs') {
      vars <- c(vars, paste('sd.', x, sep = ''))
    }
    m <- min(model.parms[[x]], 5)
    for (i in 1:m) {
      if(i == 1 && x == 'site') {
        vars <- c(vars, 'beta.site[1]')
      }
      if (i > 1) {
        vars <- c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It has been bothering me terribly, and I have failed the last two times I have tried to replace it, although conceptually it should be able to be written in a few lines. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

This bit:

```
for (i in 1:m) {
  if(i == 1 && x == 'site') {
    vars <- c(vars, 'beta.site[1]')
  }
  if (i > 1) {
    vars <- c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
  }
}
```

Says handle the first pass differently from all the others.  So I would replace it with this:

```
if (x == 'site') {
  vars <- c(vars, 'beta.site[1]')
}
for (i in 2:m) {
  vars <- c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The big mistake  in your code is you are dynamically growing your vectors. For example, compare

```
x = NULL 
for(i in 1:100000)
   x = c(x, i)
```

with

```
x = numeric(100000)
for(i in 1:100000) 
   x[i] = i
```

The other key point is that `paste` function can be vectorised. So,

```
for (i in 1:m) {
  if(i == 1 && x == 'site') {
    vars <- c(vars, 'beta.site[1]')
   }
   if (i > 1) {
     vars <- c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
   }
 }
```

can be replaced with

```
if(x == 'site') {
    vars <- c(vars, 'beta.site[1]')
   }
vars = c(vars, paste('beta.', x, '[', i, ']', sep=''))
```